# Any subtraction carryover visualization ideas?

Tags: visualization

I want to teach my kid carryover by using some sort of visualization. It can be a graph/visualization using a mathematics software or may be some sort of real world object shuffling or anything else.

I have installed sage software and tried to see in case it generates any plots. But realized I need to have concept clarity wrt how we want to visualize.

I have also tried to see in case we can visualize using the mapping between the digits in question like listing the tuples 18 to 9 for 9, 17 to 8 for 8....then some how visualize this?? But did not get ideas, root of this problem ..kind of folding at 10?? How to visualize all this easily??

Any thoughts and solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use a more in real life example to give them the idea.
For example, Lets say your Kid likes pizza, so say each pie of pizza has 10 slices.

Take an example of 
 52
-17

Tell your kid that he walks into a pizza place looking for 7 slices but there are only 2 slices of pizza. So he goes and brings a new pizza making the 5 a 4(5 pizzas left are now four) and on the right there are now 12 slices of pizza but your kid only wants 7 so he eats 7 and it leaves behind a 5.

I suppose this should make it a lot easier than showing a kid graphs or anything more complicated.

Comment: this example works and helps in explaining many more such concepts